# Add additional label to gauge using gauge.js library

Tags: javascript, canvas, gauge

I use [gauge.js](http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/) library for drawing gauges
Is there is any option how to add such or similar label to gauge( selected with red on picture)
[image]

Comment: With that rep you already should know how to ask ..? Would stickers do?

Comment: `FunkyGraphic.gauge.addLabel('Power')`

Comment: @Teemu,I updated question,I forgot to add that I use gauge.js,not pure canvas